# Filtering and Grouping data from table with key/value pairs

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with extracting data from a 'normalized' database of CSV-style data for a data collection environment. This will be done using PHP/MySQL/JSON and the purpose is to plot the data. I think I have the filtering part, but I need help with pivoting. The idea is to use the keyNames fields as a filter for the data.

Here is the query:

```
select d.testId,d.rowId,f.keyName,f.keyValue from tests t 
inner join data d on t.testId = d.testId 
inner join data c on t.testId = c.testId and c.rowId = d.rowId 
join data f on f.testId = t.testId and f.rowId = d.rowId 
where (d.keyName = 'voltage' and d.keyValue < 5) and (c.keyName = 'temperature' and c.keyValue = 30) and (t.testType = 'testType1');
```

And Results:

```
+--------+-------+-------------+----------+
| testId | rowId | keyName     | keyValue |
+--------+-------+-------------+----------+
|      1 |     1 | voltage     |        4 |
|      1 |     1 | temperature |       30 |
|      1 |     1 | velocity    |       20 |
|      1 |     2 | voltage     |        4 |
|      1 |     2 | temperature |       30 |
|      1 |     2 | velocity    |       21 |
|      2 |     1 | voltage     |        4 |
|      2 |     1 | temperature |       30 |
|      2 |     1 | velocity    |       30 |
|      2 |     2 | voltage     |        4 |
|      2 |     2 | temperature |       30 |
|      2 |     2 | velocity    |       31 |
+--------+-------+-------------+----------+
```

I would like to pivot this into: testId,rowId,voltage,temperature,velocity , such as:

```
+--------+-------+---------+-------------+----------+
| testId | rowId | voltage | temperature | velocity |
+--------+-------+---------+-------------+----------+
|      1 |     1 |       4 |          30 |       20 |
|      1 |     2 |       4 |          30 |       21 |
|      2 |     1 |       4 |          30 |       30 |
|      2 |     2 |       4 |          30 |       31 |
+--------+-------+---------+-------------+----------+
```

Any ideas? I feel like I'm close with this:

```
mysql> select f.testId,f.rowId,(if(f.keyName='voltage',f.keyValue,NULL)) as 'voltage',(if(f.keyName='temperature',f.keyValue,NULL)) as 'temperature',(if(f.keyName='velocity',f.keyValue,NULL)) as 'velocity' from tests t  inner join data d on t.testId = d.testId  inner join data c on t.testId = c.testId and c.rowId = d.rowId  join data f on f.testId = t.testId and f.rowId = d.rowId  where (d.keyName = 'voltage' and d.keyValue < 5) and (c.keyName = 'temperature' and c.keyValue = 30) and (t.testType = 'testType1');
+--------+-------+---------+-------------+----------+
| testId | rowId | voltage | temperature | velocity |
+--------+-------+---------+-------------+----------+
|      1 |     1 |       4 |        NULL |     NULL |
|      1 |     1 |    NULL |          30 |     NULL |
|      1 |     1 |    NULL |        NULL |       20 |
|      1 |     2 |       4 |        NULL |     NULL |
|      1 |     2 |    NULL |          30 |     NULL |
|      1 |     2 |    NULL |        NULL |       21 |
|      2 |     1 |       4 |        NULL |     NULL |
|      2 |     1 |    NULL |          30 |     NULL |
|      2 |     1 |    NULL |        NULL |       30 |
|      2 |     2 |       4 |        NULL |     NULL |
|      2 |     2 |    NULL |          30 |     NULL |
|      2 |     2 |    NULL |        NULL |       31 |
+--------+-------+---------+-------------+----------+
```

Here is the table definition and data source for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `ptId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `testId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rowId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyName` text NOT NULL,
  `keyValue` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ptId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=33 ;

INSERT INTO `data` (`ptId`, `testId`, `rowId`, `keyName`, `keyValue`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'voltage', 4),
(2, 1, 1, 'temperature', 30),
(3, 1, 1, 'velocity', 20),
(4, 1, 2, 'voltage', 4),
(5, 1, 2, 'temperature', 30),
(6, 1, 2, 'velocity', 21),
(7, 1, 3, 'voltage', 3),
(8, 1, 3, 'temperature', 35),
(9, 1, 3, 'velocity', 22),
(10, 1, 4, 'voltage', 3),
(11, 1, 4, 'temperature', 35),
(12, 1, 4, 'velocity', 23),
(13, 2, 1, 'voltage', 4),
(14, 2, 1, 'temperature', 30),
(15, 2, 1, 'velocity', 30),
(16, 2, 2, 'voltage', 4),
(17, 2, 2, 'temperature', 30),
(18, 2, 2, 'velocity', 31),
(19, 2, 3, 'voltage', 5),
(20, 2, 3, 'temperature', 35),
(21, 2, 3, 'velocity', 32),
(22, 2, 4, 'voltage', 5),
(23, 2, 4, 'temperature', 35),
(24, 2, 4, 'velocity', 33),
(25, 4, 1, 'voltage', 4),
(26, 4, 1, 'velocity', 30),
(27, 4, 2, 'voltage', 4),
(28, 4, 2, 'velocity', 31),
(29, 4, 3, 'voltage', 5),
(30, 4, 3, 'velocity', 32),
(31, 4, 4, 'voltage', 5),
(32, 4, 4, 'velocity', 33);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tests` (
  `testId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Unique Test ID',
  `testType` text NOT NULL,
  `startDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `userName` text NOT NULL,
  `testSoftware` text NOT NULL,
  `comments` text,
  `dutID` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`testId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

INSERT INTO `tests` (`testId`, `testType`, `startDate`, `userName`, `testSoftware`, `comments`, `dutID`) VALUES
(1, 'testType1', '2013-03-23 21:06:10', 'testUser1', 'testSoftware1', NULL, 'dut1'),
(2, 'testType1', '2013-03-23 21:10:32', 'testUser1', 'testSoftware1', NULL, 'dut1'),
(3, 'testType1', '2013-03-23 21:10:32', 'testUser1', 'testSoftware1', NULL, 'dut1'),
(4, 'testType2', '2013-03-23 21:10:32', 'testUser1', 'testSoftware1', NULL, 'dut1');
```

Comment: How much are you paying us?

Comment: This isn't for a paid application.. how was that comment helpful?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here, just a list of things you wan't to achieve. Please ask a specific question and I'm sure you'll get a good, helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is you are using an aggregate function in the SELECT list but you are not using a `GROUP BY`.  You should be using a `GROUP BY` similar to this:

```
GROUP BY d.testId, d.rowId
```

Whenever you are using an aggregate function and you have other columns in your select, they should be in a group by. So your full query should be:

```
select d.testId,
  d.rowId,
  max(if(f.keyName='voltage',f.keyValue,NULL)) as 'voltage',
  max(if(f.keyName='temperature',f.keyValue,NULL)) as 'temperature',
  max(if(f.keyName='velocity',f.keyValue,NULL)) as 'velocity' 
from tests t  
inner join data d 
  on t.testId = d.testId  
inner join data c 
  on t.testId = c.testId 
  and c.rowId = d.rowId  
join data f 
  on f.testId = t.testId 
  and f.rowId = d.rowId  
where (d.keyName = 'voltage' and d.keyValue < 5) 
  and (c.keyName = 'temperature' and c.keyValue = 30) 
  and (t.testType = 'testType1')
GROUP BY d.testId, d.rowId
```

Note, while your actual data structure is not presented in your original question.  It appears that this can be consolidated to the following:

```
select d.testid,
  d.rowid,
  max(case when d.keyName = 'voltage' and d.keyValue < 5 then d.keyValue end) voltage,
  max(case when d.keyName = 'temperature' and d.keyValue =30 then d.keyValue end) temperature,
  max(case when d.keyName = 'velocity' then d.keyValue end) velocity
from tests t
left join data d
  on t.testid = d.testid
group by d.testid, d.rowid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07c99/1).  This gives the result with only one join to the `data` table:

```
| TESTID | ROWID | VOLTAGE | TEMPERATURE | VELOCITY |
-----------------------------------------------------
|      1 |     1 |       4 |          30 |       20 |
|      1 |     2 |       4 |          30 |       21 |
|      2 |     1 |       4 |          30 |       30 |
|      2 |     2 |       4 |          30 |       31 |
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! Looks like group by was the missing key. I tried your optimization and I don't think it performs the logical AND I need. I am trying out your original solution to see if I understand it properly and that it works for my needs. I have updated the original post to include the data structure and sample data.

Comment: @jdhar Based on the sample data that you provided what do you want the result to be?

Comment: I have included a desired output, which your first query achieves. The idea is to use any combination of keyName to keyField comparisons to filter out the data (the example I gave is temperature = 30 and voltage < 5). So it looks like to add fields, I just replicate the inner join blocks.